# How to use Accept header in nginx index

Tags: nginx

I want to serve a markdown version of my blog. Imagine `http://myblog.com/some/post/` and two requests:

- `Accept: text/html` -> `http://myblog.com/some/post/index.html`
- `Accept: text/markdown` -> `http://myblog.com/some/post/index.md`

How do I configure nginx to do this?

I read [the documentation on `index`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html) but it didn't mention content negotiation at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need to use content negotiation with your index files, you could use the `index` directive with a variable defined using a `map`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) for details.

For example:

```
map $http_accept $myindex {
    default          index.html;
    ~*text/markdown  index.md;
}

index $myindex index.html;
```